# GDB on Mac just as administrator...?

Tags: macos, gdb, osx-lion

I can use GDB just from administrator.

When I launch GDB as a normal user, after giving the GDB command "run", a dialog requests me for a user name and password of a user in the "Developer Tools" group.

The problem is that I already am in the "Developer Tools" group, so I do not know what else to do...

Thank you!

Platform:

- MacOS X 10.7.1
- GCC 4.2.1
- i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
- GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1705)
- This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

Now I know that the groups shown in the GUI are not the real ones ;-)